# SilverStripe - Pass data from controller to html form through jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, silverstripe

I am working on a form which has 2 dropdowns: Service Requested and Locations. Whenever the user picks a service then the locations dropdown should be populated with those locations that have been selected for that service. I have an admin model for Service and Location, and here is the one for Service to show how I mapped the Locations model data to it:

```
<?php
class Service extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'varchar',
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Locations' => 'Location'
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'Name' => 'Title',
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
        'Name'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($this->ID) {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Locations', CheckboxSetField::create(
                'Locations',
                'Locations',
                Location::get()->filter(array(
                    'AcceptingAppointments' => '1'
                ))->map()
            ));
        }

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

This is the jQuery related to the dropdown for Service Requested followed by the ajax function that is passing the id to the server:

```
  SchService.change(function() {
  if (SchService.val() != "" && SchService.val() != null) {
    SchLocation.prop('disabled', false);
    sendServiceId();
  } else {
    SchLocation.prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

  function sendServiceId(){
   var service_data = {
     serviceid: SchService.find('option:selected').attr('id')
   };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/getLocationsByService",
        data: service_data
    }).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
}
```

And finally, the function for getLocationsByService, which is using the Service id from the ajax call to retrieve the locations for that service:

```
 public function getLocationsByService(){
    $serviceid = $this->getRequest()->getVar('serviceid');
    $service = Service::get()->byId($serviceid);
    $locations = Service::Locations();
    foreach ($locations as $location){
        return json_encode($locations);//not sure if this will be needed
    }
}
```

I'm confused now on how to parse the location data retrieved in a manner that can be returned to the form for use in the Locations dropdown field. I am guessing json may be needed but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: 1. I think ajax should have 'success' param where the return data would be processed. Also, when you have got foreach loop and 'return' in it, the loop will last only 1 revolution, it will not be repeated as you are breaking it with 'return', I would advise uou tu return whole array ($locations) and process it with JS in the AJAX success function :)

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the answer you are after, but I'd recommend using a great module for this instead... https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-dependentdropdownfield

This is the example that is offers...

```
// 1. Create a callable function that returns an array of options for the DependentDropdownField. 
// When the value of the field it depends on changes, this function is called passing the 
// updated value as the first parameter ($val)
$datesSource = function($val) { 
    if ($val == 'one') {
        // return appropriate options array if the value is one.
    }
    if ($val == 'two') {
        // return appropriate options array if the value is two.
    }
}; 

$fields = FieldList::create(
    // 2. Add your first field to your field list, 
    $fieldOne = DropdownField::create('FieldOne', 'Field One', array('one' => 'One', 'two' => 'Two')),
    // 3. Add your DependentDropdownField, setting the source as the callable function 
    // you created and setting the field it depends on to the appropriate field
    DependentDropdownField::create('FieldTwo', 'Field Two', $datesSource)->setDepends($fieldOne)
);
```

Comment: I have seen this plugin but I don't think it will work for me in this case. Each Service can have its own list of locations, and there are 30+ services total. If I have to code each one with its own selection of services using this plugin, that won't save me much time in the end.

Comment: you define a php function that takes the selected value from one drop down to then return the options for the second one.  The point is that all the ajax stuff is written for you and you *only* deal with that one php function to say "if this Service is selected, then these Locations are returned" or vice versa depending on your exact requirements

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer and include an example? Link only answers are considered to be not useful for stackoverflow and might be deleted.